# Seeking best way to step up voltage from battery to power motor

Tags: arduino, voltage, power, batteries, stepper-motor

I apologize if I'm asking a really simple/stupid question here, or if this is an xy problem and I'm missing something entirely. I'm someone working way outside my field here since electrical systems and especially power supplies are not anywhere close to my usual area of work.

I'm currently tasked with developing a system that is mounted on a drone. Driving this system is a stepper motor which is controlled by an Arduino Nano. The problem I'm running into, however, is that in order to keep the weight down because drones, I have to use a PM-stepper motor compared to the much heavier hybrid stepper motors.The voltages of the motors I have access to are either 24V or 15V, but then the weight of the batteries I'd be looking at to  supply that voltage would be heavier than the drone could lift.

I'm looking for a lightweight circuit design to use fewer/lighter batteries to produce both the 24V to drive the motor as well as provide a lower voltage power to the Arduino which has an input voltage limit of 21V.

---

Part numbers:

- 15V stepper option - PG15S-D20-HHB9
- 24V stepper option - PG25L-D24-HHC1
- Arduino - ABX00027

Comment: Have you read something of this? https://realpars.com/stepper-motors-advantages/#:~:text=Stepper%20Motors%20provide%20ruggedness%2C%20high,will%20work%20in%20many%20environments.&text=Some%20of%20the%20top%20Stepper%20Motor%20disadvantages%20are%20in,motors%20provide%20a%20low%20efficiency.

Comment: Can the Stepper motor be replaced by a "servo-motor"?

Comment: The question is a bit broad. Battery weight and voltage are not correlated, try to estimate the available and needed energy first.

Comment: Radio controlled models use powerful but lightweight brushless motors, not stepper motors. Many use 8.4V max (2 lithium cells), 12.6V max (3 lithium cells) or 16.8V max (4 lithium cells). The lithium batteries are made in many sizes and are lightweight. If you stepup the voltage of a battery then its current is increased the same amount then its discharge time is very short.

Comment: @Antonio51 It needs to be a stepper motor since holding torque is necessary since it will be winding and holding a constant force spring, I need it to be able to do continuous 360 rotation, and I need some form of positional accuracy. So servos & DC are out and steppers are what I need.

Comment: @Audioguru, I am not creating a drone with a stepper motor, this is a system that attaches to a preexisting commercial drone for a research project that I was put on. I cannot use a DC motor for reasons I posted in my response above, and I also can't just buy a stack of batteries to get to the adequate voltage because the drone has to carry both the weight of the apparatus & the weight of the batteries, and it is just a small commecrial drone with ~400g payload capacity

Comment: @Jens I'm not trained to know even where to begin on energy capacity needs, I'm a programmer and VR developer, not an elec or mech engineer. I'm learning as I go between the components, fusion 360, manufacturing, etc. since I had to take on a research project when the original person who it was intended for couldn't do it and I'm on my own taking care of it now. 

I posted the parts are available to order within the timeframe that I can get them in time before the research period ends. If you can look at them and advise me on the numbers you are looking at, please let me know.

Comment: Sorry. I have never seen a winch on a drone.

Answer (score 0):

I will bring together some thoughts here:

1. The mentioned payload of the system is 400g. If you take the motor PG25L-D24-HHC1, there are 57g. Using two LiPo 18650 3Ah cells with protection there are +100g. Arduino Nano is +7g, a boost converter +15g maximum, stepper motor driver module again about +15g. Add some wires and you are at about 200g for a raw working system. The remaining 200g can be filled with additional cells in parallel, a housing and other mechanical components needed.
2. The 2 LiPo cells provide a usable voltage range from 7.2-8.4V, for a run time estimation I take 7.8V. If I give the motor 200 mA continous current at 24 V and assume 90% efficiency for the boost converter, this will draw around 684 mA from the battery. Add 20 mA for the Arduino and 10 mA for the stepper driver module and the total current consumption will be 714 mA. This would run for a bit more than 4 hours using the 3Ah cells.
3. Adding a second DC/DC converter from battery voltage down to 5V for the Arduino improves the battery efficiency slightly but adds weight, I don't think its worth the effort. So feed the Arduino directly from the battery using Vin.
4. Do not use a stepper driver with bipolar output stages as mentioned in the motor datasheet, the efficiency is too bad. There are a lot of driver chips with internal current control PWM and step/dir interface, often seen in 3D printers.

There are many assumptions here, it is possible to allow up to 500 mA for the motor having less than 2 hours run time. The 200 mA guess was derived from the less powerful capabilities of the other motor. I just don't know what torque you may need in this application.